# Собрать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Пытаюсь собрать `$amount` массивов:

```
$phpObj = json_decode($json);
    $amount = count($phpObj->devices);    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        $latitude = print_r($phpObj->devices[$i]->latitude, true);
        $longitude = print_r($phpObj->devices[$i]->longitude, true);
        $array = [
            $i = [
                'latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude
            ]
        ];
    }
    echo '<pre>';print_r($array);
```

На выходе всего один подмассив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 50.463772
            [longitude] => 30.609599
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При каждой новой итерации вы заново объявляете массив $array

Необходимо объявить его до цикла, а в цикле добавлять значения.

```
$phpObj = json_decode($json);
$amount = count($phpObj->devices); 
$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
    $latitude = print_r($phpObj->devices[$i]->latitude, true);
    $longitude = print_r($phpObj->devices[$i]->longitude, true);
    $array[$i] = [
        'latitude' => $latitude, 'longitude' => $longitude
    ];
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($array);
```